# Chrome DevTools - Request Header Size

Tags: request, chrome, headers

Is there a way to get the total size (in bytes) of the request header that the browser is sending to the server for each request?

Answer (score 16):

Sort of...

1. go to the network tab and right click the first item and click copy as cURL (this is how you will get the header size.
2. Then go to terminal and do your curl command `curl ... -w '%{size_request} %{size_upload}'` which will print out the request size at the end.

Curl is the only way i know of doing it.

Comment: exactly. what I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: I just think it's strange that the Chrome Devtools make any selection here.